# How can I normalize price data for 2 financial instruments from different categories?

Tags: pairs-trading, normalization

Lets say I want to build a divergence / convergence strategy with FOREX currency pair and a correlated commodity. How can I normalize the prices so that I get an accurate idea of the movements of each, relative to each other? Obviously a move of 10¢ is much more significant on a currency pair than on a commodity. And how can I keep the data properly normalized over time, as new data continues to come in?

Comment: One suggestion: work with Percentage Returns, not price levels. (Or if you need a level build a Cumulative Return Index for each instrument, starting at 100).

Comment: What noob2 said is the way to do this.  You could alternatively calculate Z-scores, but there isn't a compelling reason to do that here since differences in vol are likely part of what you're trying to assess.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into that!